# Converting a grid from a text file to a numpy multidimensional array with consistent axis coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, text

I wonder if anyone could help me with this issue, which I can handle in 2 dimensions... but no more.

I work with text files which store data grids as tables. Each column represents an axis coordinate value, except the last one which is the actual data.

This code generates an example of the 2D array you would load from the text file:

```
import numpy as np


def function_a(a, b, c, d):
    return a + b + c + d/100000


w = np.arange(6.0, 9.0, 0.5)
x = np.arange(1, 1000, 200)
y = np.arange(-4.0, -1.5, 0.5)
z = np.arange(1e6, 1e7, 1e6)

file_matrix = np.zeros((w.size*x.size*y.size*z.size, 5))
i = 0
for w_value in w:
    for x_value in x:
        for y_value in y:
            for z_value in z:
                file_matrix[i, 0] = w_value
                file_matrix[i, 1] = x_value
                file_matrix[i, 2] = y_value
                file_matrix[i, 3] = z_value
                file_matrix[i, 4] = function_a(w_value, x_value, y_value, z_value)
                i += 1

print(file_matrix)
```

As you can see in this table each column coordinate has a different "step velocity" the first column changes in value slower than second and so for every subsequent column coordinate. The last one changes at every row:

```
[[ 6.000e+00  1.000e+00 -4.000e+00  1.000e+06  1.300e+01]
 [ 6.000e+00  1.000e+00 -4.000e+00  2.000e+06  2.300e+01]
 [ 6.000e+00  1.000e+00 -4.000e+00  3.000e+06  3.300e+01]
 ...
 [ 8.500e+00  8.010e+02 -2.000e+00  7.000e+06  8.775e+02]
 [ 8.500e+00  8.010e+02 -2.000e+00  8.000e+06  8.875e+02]
 [ 8.500e+00  8.010e+02 -2.000e+00  9.000e+06  8.975e+02]]
```

I would like o reshape this matrix to a 4-dimensional array (let's call it `file_mdimArray`) which considers the axis increments of the w, x, y, z arrays. So that:

```
file_mdimArray[a, b, c, d] = function_a(w[a], x[b], y[c], z[d])
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Bit confusing. What should the output of `function_a(w[1], x[1], y[2], z[3])` be?

Comment: @not_speshal sorry for that, I shall improve the conclusion: I meant that in the correct scenario, the multidimensional array should the return the  same value as the function for the same coordinates (w, x, y, z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape your array as I show in the following code to reach the shape you describe.

```
file_mdimArray = file_matrix[:, 4].reshape(len(w), len(x), len(y), len(z))
```

I would also advise you to change the way you compute the array file_matrix. You can do it without using loops by utilizing tools provided by numpy.

```
ww, xx, yy, zz = np.meshgrid(w, x, y, z, indexing='ij')
ww, xx, yy, zz = [i.flatten() for i in [ww, xx, yy, zz]]
file_matrix = np.stack([ww, xx, yy, zz, function_a(ww, xx, yy, zz)])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That work just how I wanted it! So stupid I could not find the right method to do it.